# Oracle - Format return of sysdate inside select

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I did a select in oracle database to return the time that ticket is in a support group.

Sometimes, I have the scenario where we have the date of ticket joined the group, but I'm not out of time.

To workaround this problem, I put in my select a condition and worked with diff between the date of entry in the group and the sysdate.

The problem is the output that is being formatted as follows: `+00 00:28:32.00000`, and I need only the time in minutes.

Below, I added the whole query, I suppose that the problem is in this part:

```
CASE
WHEN PBTI_TEMPONOGRUPO IS NULL
THEN (SYSDATE-(SECS_TO_DATE(PBTI_DATAENTRADAGRUPO)))
END AS TEMPO_NO_GRUPO
```

How to format this output?

**The query is:**

```
SELECT PBTI_WORKORDER_ID         AS ID_WO,
       PBTI_IDREQUISICAO         AS ID_REQ,
       PBTI_GRUPOSUPORTEATUAL    AS GRUPO_SUP_ATUAL,
       PBTI_GRUPOSUPORTEANTERIOR AS GRUPO_SUP_ANTERIOR,

       CASE
       WHEN PBTI_DATASAIDAGRUPO IS NULL
       THEN SYSDATE
       WHEN PBTI_DATASAIDAGRUPO IS NOT NULL
       THEN SECS_TO_DATE(PBTI_DATASAIDAGRUPO)
       END       AS DATA_SAIDA_GRUPO,

       SECS_TO_DATE(PBTI_DATAENTRADAGRUPO) AS DATA_ENTRADA,

       CASE
       WHEN PBTI_TEMPONOGRUPO IS NULL
       THEN (SYSDATE-(SECS_TO_DATE(PBTI_DATAENTRADAGRUPO)))
       END       AS TEMPO_NO_GRUPO

  FROM PBTI_TABELA_INDICADORES
 WHERE PBTI_WORKORDER_ID = 'WO0000000142585';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
WHEN PBTI_DATASAIDAGRUPO IS NULL
THEN SYSDATE
WHEN PBTI_DATASAIDAGRUPO IS NOT NULL
THEN SECS_TO_DATE(PBTI_DATASAIDAGRUPO)
END
```

So the output of the **CASE** expressions will be **DATE data type**. To get the output in your desired format, use **TO_CHAR** along with desired **FORMAT MODEL** to convert it into a string.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') only_date FROM DUAL;

ONLY_DATE
----------
2015-10-20

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') only_time FROM DUAL;

ONLY_TIME
---------
20:29:54
```

Comment: Tks Lalit. 
maybe I have expressed myself badly. I'm trying to make a difference between the sysdate and to date I have in my system (which is natively in seconds). this time, redid a part of the expression, but the outcome is not yet certain. What I did was:THEN ROUND((((SYSDATE - DATE '1969-12-31')*24*60*60)-(PBTI_DATAENTRADAGRUPO))/60)

Comment: I tried to do the sysdate - timestamp, but the format is giving error. and subtraction is wrong. =(

Comment: @Barcat The difference between two dates is **NUMBER** of days. You can't do `sysdate - timestamp` because they are different data types. `timestamp` is an extension to the `date` data type. I am not able to get your requirement. If you are doing a diff between dates, the result is number of days, to which you are converting to seconds. Now what is the question?